# How to iterate through 2 lists at once?

Tags: python

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f: 
        doSomething(line)
```

Is there a way to iterate through two files at once? Here's some pseudo code to help you understand..

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f: and with open ('myfile2.txt') as d:
    for line in f and for line2 in d:
        doSomething(line, line2)
```

Comment: `zip`... .... .... ....

Comment: why don't you use zip()?

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f, open('myfile2.txt') as d:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f, d):
        do_something(line1, line2)
```

Note that, for Python 2, you should use `itertools.izip` - it only holds one pair of lines in memory at a time, rather than returning a list of all pairs of lines.

Comment: Will the `with` apply to the second file as well?

Comment: @keyser: yes, it will.

Comment: Yup, noticed it in the duplicate link above :)

Comment: Do I have the wrong syntax? I thought it was `with open('path/to/file1') as f_one and open('path/to/file2') as f_two`. Note that this only works in Python2.7+. Hmm I guess I do, as per the dupe listed by Dave Yarwood. Dang!